# Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object()

Tags: object, fetch

Good afternoon!

I need help with the follow code, it have a error! and the true i'm new in this.

```
Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_object()
```

The code is:

```
 $mysqli=conectar(); 
       $sql="SELECT nombre FROM admin WHERE user=".$_SESSION['admin']; // carga el nombre del usuario de la sesión
       $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
       $linea=$mysqli->fetch_object($resultado);
        echo $linea;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are calling the method fetch_object() on a mysqli object. 
The signature of fetch_object (OO style) is :

```
object mysqli_result::fetch_object ([ string $class_name [, array $params ]] )
```

So, you have to call the method on a `mysqli_result` object. It should be like this :

```
 $mysqli=conectar(); 
 $sql="SELECT nombre FROM admin WHERE user=".$_SESSION['admin']; // carga el nombre del usuario de la sesión
 $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
 $linea=$resultado->fetch_object();
 echo $linea->nombre; //retrieve the field 'nombre'
```

That works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem change the next mistake:

Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

The code current is:

$mysqli=conectar(); 
       $sql="SELECT nombre FROM admin WHERE user=".$_SESSION['admin']; // carga el nombre del usuario de la sesión
       $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
       //$linea=$mysqli->fetch_object($resultado);
       $linea=$resultado->fetch_object();
        echo $linea;

Comment: First of all you can't echo $linea this way. The mysqli_fetch_object() will return the current row result set as an object where the attributes of the object represent the names of the fields found within the result set. So you have to do : echo $linea->nombre from your example.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems that your request doesn't retrieve any value. That's why you get the error.